# Restrict or hide file types by user?

Tags: groups, hidden

Our SharePoint files are set up as attachments to a list. I would like add .Indd files as attachments to list entries. And want my team and I (~30 people) to be able to see and download the .Indd files. For the rest of the firm (~1,500 people) I want either the .Indd to be hidden from view or locked to prevent downloading.

Any insight/advice on how to set this up would be appreciated.

-not sure I did the best job with tags. Will change them if anyone suggest better choices.

Answer (score 1):

So you can't secure them individually as list item attachments.   The easiest way may be to keep them separate in a library where only the users that need access have permissions.

One method I can think of where you could achieve a "visual" separation is to use multiple list views and audiences.

1. Create two audiences with each group of users.
2. Add two list views - one with the attachment visible and one without it.
3. Use audience targeting to hide the view not relevant to the specific group

Again - this a visual separation, not a security boundary.  Any moderate user could get access to the actual list or list item and view the attachment.

Comment: >The easiest way may be to keep them separate in a library where only the users that need access have permissions.  

Well, I'm trying to get all the files my team needs to reside in the same place. We already have to go through two different file structures so I'm not sure putting the .indd files in a separate library would make things much easier for my team.  I've literally never heard of "audiences" in SharePoint before. When was that introduced?

Comment: 2007 at least, I don't recall if they were in the 2003 offering or not, been too long.